# Cant display array items in the inspector. Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

I want to make a class array and see all these classes items in the inspector.

I have 2 scripts. 1 -set to prefab and requires MonoBehaviour to be included.
2 - script where I create the array but in the inspector, I see only Element0, Element1...
When I remove MonoBehaviour from the 1st script I'm able to see all the items in the inspector, but that way it doesn't work with the prefab...

1-

```
[System.Serializable]
public class LevelSetup : MonoBehaviour
{

    public TextMeshProUGUI levelName;
    public Image levelImage;
    public bool locked;
    public GameObject Description;
    public string Text;


}
```

2-

```
public class LevelSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LevelSetup[] levels;
```

[image]
[image]

Want to be displayed array with all the "LevelSetup" fields (that are public), but if I leave the MonoBehaviour and it works fine with prefab it displays array with the only Element0, Element1, etc.
Thank You!

Comment: The inspector by default only shows the content of the variable you list, if you want to see the properties of stuff in an array, you would need to overwrite the inspector and list it to draw them

Comment: @BugFinder but when I remove 'MonoBehaviour' I'm able to see all the stuff (2nd pic). Why?

Comment: because monobehaviors are different to other classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a field that inherits from MonoBehaviour the Unity's inspector expects an object that has "Behaviour", so you cannot assign the fields in the inspector because is not interpreted as a regular field.

For example, if you set a Material as a field, and you want to change the color property from the inspector.

```
public Material mat; //This is actually a class
```

In the inspector you will only be able to assign a material but you won't be able to access inside the class and change the color.